# SQL joining 2 tables to see differences

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that I would like to join to easily see the differences between them divided by sections specified in one column (type). 
To give an example:

Table1:

```
Type1|Data1
Type1|Data2
Type2|Data3
```

Table2:

```
Type1|Data1
Type2|Data5
Type2|Data6
```

Expected result:

```
Type1|Data1|Type1|Data1
Type1|Data2|null|null
Type2|Data3|Type2|Data5
null |null|Type2|Data6
```

how can i achieve this? there is no unique identifier i could bind these tables on

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: In your example why `Type2|Data3` matches `Type2|Data5` but not `Type2|Data6`?

Comment: What's the rule to join both tables? It's not clear to me.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: enumerating values and using full join as suggested by Gordon below solved my issue! so happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to enumerate the values and then use a `full join`:

```
select t1.type, t1.data, t2.type, t2.data
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by type) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by type) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.type = t2.type and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Comment: This solution should be used with care since it doesn't use a deterministic order. In simple words, it may work today, but not tomorrow morning. Maybe the `order by` in the partition should include the second column as well. I won't downvote since it's close.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that none of the values in the source tables are `NULL`s, you could use a `FULL JOIN` on all columns.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
            FULL JOIN table2 t2
                      ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
                         AND t1.column2 = t2.column2;
```

All pairs of values stored in both tables will be repeated in a line. If a pair is present in one table, but not in the other, the values for the other will read `NULL`.

To only see the different rows this can be refined to:

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
            FULL JOIN table2 t2
                      ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
                         AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
       WHERE t1.column1 IS NULL
             OR t2.column1 IS NULL;
```

That should enable you to see the differences. But it won't produce your "`Type2|Data3|Type2|Data5`" row. I didn't get what the logic behind this row should be? Maybe just joining in `column1` as [The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler) commented will bring you closer to this, though it won't produce the desired result posted with the data posted.

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1 t1
            FULL JOIN table2 t2
                      ON t1.column1 = t2.column1;
```

Comment: Maybe just joining `column1`?

Comment: @TheImpaler: Maybe closer but still not it. But worth to mention anyway, thanks.

Comment: i just wanted to join these tables as they are, like comparing 2 excel tables, Gordon solved my question below :)